# AS Cohen Macaulay algebras and dualizing complexes

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

Let $A$ be an $\mathbb N$-graded algebra such that $A_0 = k$ is a field. This are usually called graded connected algebras.

One can define a torsion functor with respect to the ideal $\mathfrak m = \bigoplus_{i \geq 1} A_i$, setting for any graded $A$ module $M$

$$\Gamma_{\mathfrak m}(M) = \{m \in M | A_{\geq i}m = 0 \mbox{ for } i \gg 0 \} \cong \varinjlim_i Hom_A(A/A_{\geq i},M).$$

The derived functors of $\Gamma_{\mathfrak m}$ are the local cohomology functors with respect to $\mathfrak m$, and are denoted by $H^i_\mathfrak m$. As in the commutative case, there is a natural isomorphism
 $$H_\mathfrak m(-) \cong \varinjlim Ext_A^i(A/A_{\geq i}, -)$$

We say $A$ is

- AS Cohen Macaulay if there is a natural number $n$ such that $H_\mathfrak m^i (A) = H_\mathfrak m(A^{op}) = 0$. Let us call $n$ the local dimension of the module $A$ (I'm not sure this is standard notation)
- AS Gorenstein if it has finite injective dimension $n$ both as a right and left module, and furthermore $Ext_A^n(k,A) = k$, once again on both sides.

This are generalizations of ye olde condition of regularity for graded connected algebras introduced by Artin and Schelter, hence the AS. If $A$ is commutative and noetherian, then they are equivalent to their AS-less counterparts. (Maybe you can drop the noetherian hypothesis on this, but I'm not sure.)

We have the usual implication chain

> AS regular $\Rightarrow$ AS Gorenstein $\Rightarrow$ AS Cohen Macaulay.

By Groethendick's vanishing theorem, if $A$ is a noetherian Cohen Macaulay algebra of local dimension $n$, then $H^i_\mathfrak m \equiv 0$ for $i > n$.

**Question 1**: Is this result still true for noncommutative noetherian AS Cohen Macaulay algebras?

The result is true for noetherian AS Gorenstein algebras, as explained in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Yekutieli&s5=Serre&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq) by Yekutieli and Zhang, Corollary 4.3. The argument comes basically from the fact that AS Gorenstein algebras have balanced dualizing complexes, almost by definition. This brings me to my

**Question 2**: Are there AS Cohen Macaulay algebras *without* (balanced or unbalanced) dualizing complexes?

Thanks!